# Буквы Э на конце

Tags: орфография

Как все-таки правильно: "аниме" или "анимэ", "каратэ" или "карате"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аниме и карате. Про карате - в любом орфографическом словаре можете посмотреть.
Некоторые не первой свежести толковые словари по старинке дают "каратэ", но тут они не авторитетны, ориентируйтесь именно на орфографические. "Аниме" словарями пока не фиксируется, но можно вполне уверено сказать, что там Е.

Давно уже сошлись на том, что буква Э в русском нормативно используется только в абсолютном начале слова, в приставочных производных от таких слов, и (редко) после гласных в заимствованных словах. Исключение - несколько односложных слов, где э используется для словоразличения и изредко - имена собственные (топонимы и личные имена и фамилии). Не могу скзазать, что это всегда и во всем удачное решение, но так оно есть.